# Open the desired slide on click Swiper.js

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

In my project, I use a modal window and swiper.js. I have a photo gallery and I want a slider to open with the photo I click on. Instead, the first photo is always opened.
Opening a modal window with a PhotoBlock

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
       <>
           <div onClick={handleOpen} style={{backgroundImage: `url('${src}')`}} className={"photoBlock"}></div>
           <Modal
               className={classes.modal}
               open={open}
               onClose={handleClose}
               aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
               aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
           >
               <Swiper
                   zoom={true}
                   loop={true}
                   className={classes.swiper}
                   observer={true}
                   observeParents={true}
                   // install Swiper modules
                   modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y, Zoom]}
                   spaceBetween={50}
                   slidesPerView={1}
                   navigation
                   pagination={{ clickable: true, dynamicBullets: true }}
               >
                   {data.map( (item: any, i: number) =>(
                       <SwiperSlide
                           key={i}
                           className={classes.swiperSlider}
                       >
                           <div className="swiper-zoom-container">
                               <img className={classes.imgPhotoBlock} alt={'photo'} src={item.src}></img>
                           </div>
                       </SwiperSlide>
                   ) )}
                   <CloseOutlinedIcon onClick={handleClose} className={classes.closeIcon} sx={{ fontSize: 50 }} />
               </Swiper>
           </Modal>
       </>
    );
```

array of photos

```
const sketchesList = [
        {src:'/images/sketches/1.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/2.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/3.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/4.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/5.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/6.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/7.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/8.jpg'},
        {src:'/images/sketches/9.jpg'},
]
```

Calling the PhotoBlock

```
<div className={'photoList'} >
                            {sketchesList.map((item, index) => (
                                <PhotoBlock key={index} data={sketchesList} src={item.src}/>
                            ))}
                        </div>
```

I tried to implement this using the ref hook, because this is the most common solution for similar problems, but nothing worked for me